# What does "exit status 1" mean in ScraperWiki, is it a failure?

Tags: screen-scraping, scraperwiki

A user was getting this message from a scraper run.

```
Run succeeded: - ran 1 times, most recently for 2073 seconds (288                                                     
scraped pages, 2 records) 17:45, 5 May 2011 Hide Details                                                              
EXECUTIONSTATUS: uml=uml003                                                                                           
runid=1304613933.039043_3bf3b898b74f46d9e85aa2189ce9e1ee2c7a328c                                                      

EXECUTIONSTATUS: 2071 seconds elapsed, 142 CPU seconds used, exit status 1
```

What is "exit status 1"? Is that a success or a failure? If it's a
failure, is there a log file?

Answer (score 2):

The "exit status" is just a display of the Unix-style exit status of the Ruby script.

e.g. If you did "exit 73" from a Ruby script, it would display exit status 73.

In Unix, 0 means no error, so 1 does mean an error of some sort, or something behaving incorrectly.

The logging system is simply to use print (or more usefully, puts) statements. You'll be able to see this in the history window for scheduled runs, or in the console while running in development.